# How to get Parceable Data from Intent in ActivityMangerService?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-source

Such as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("some action");
intent.putExtra("data",parcelData);//the parcelData is a Parceable Object
startActivity(intent);
```

With the `StartActivity` function called, before `Instrumentation.java` call `ActivityManger.getService().startActivity(...)`, I can get all parcel data from debug progress.

After I it run into `ActivityMangerService.startActivity(...)` ,i can not get any data from the funciotn field(`intent`), when the target activity of the intent started, i can get all data in Bundle.

So what happened in `ActivityMangerService`, why i can not read any data from `services.jar` progress ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to get parcel object from the intent in ActivityManagerService, you may get an ClassNotFoundException.

The parcelData's class is only loaded in you app process, not in the system_server.

Comment: If Application A send a Intent to Application B, is it also in app progress? if do not in the system server. How the parcel data  sent from A to B?

Comment: You can define the custom parcal class in your common code or sdk. And compile A and B with you common code or sdk.